# Pass function from vector/list

Tags: r

I'd like to go from

```
myVector = c(function(x){x^2})
myFunction = myVector[[1]]
curve(myFunction)
```

to

```
myVector = c(function(x){x^2})
curve(myVector[[1]])
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work.

Use case: function returns vector/list, which contains another function, of values based on arguments

Comment: Check out the documentation for `?curve`. The first parameter can be "the name of a function, or a call or an expression written as a function of x which will evaluate to an object of the same length as x." In your first case you are passing the name of an object that points to a function. In the second, you are not. The `[[]]` is basically a function call, you are not passing in a name, you are passing in an expression and that expression is not written as a function of `x`. You could do `curve(myVector[[1]](x))`

Comment: @MrFlick I find it interesting the `curve()` seems so unfriendly to a list of functions. Do you know of a way to achieve something like `lapply(list_of_funs, curve, add = TRUE)` to add multiple functions to a plot? (I mean, I know there are lots of ways, but I can't think of way to force `curve()` to do it.)

Comment: Just use `lapply(list_of_funs, function(f) curve(f, add = TRUE))`.

Comment: @joran. I think @user2554330's suggestion is as good as it gets. Curve, like most other functions that use non-standard evaulation, are great for interactive use but not so great for programmatic use. You could also write a version that forces an expression to be created with `do.call`. Maybe something like `pcurve <- function(e, ...) do.call("curve", list(bquote(.(e)(x)), ...))` but that's not very elegant, but it would work with `lapply`.